# Why do buffalos not leave the lion alone?

Tags: predation, antipredator-adaptation

In the [Buffalo Kill Lion - The Stronger is The Winner](https://youtu.be/o0xHeBI5Mxw) video the buffalos *seem* to be attacking an incapacitated lion.

**Why would they do that?**

They seem to risk injury for no gain (they don't eat lions).

Comment: The gain is one less lion to worry about.

Comment: @JAB: I have serious doubts about math capabilities of buffalos ;-)